# Usage of split() API for two special charaters.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have code like below

```
var data = "(5)"
```

Now, using split i need only number "5", need to truncate the "(" and ")".

Comment: split? Can't you use something else?

Comment: Why do you need to use `split`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use split,

```
var data = "(5)"
alert(data.split(')')[0].split('(')[1])
```

Comment: I don't using split is a wise recommendation here.. since split, slice is all native API's.. using either should be Ok. I would recommend using slice in this specific case.

Comment: yup, i agree. But the OP specifically wanted split

Answer (score 3):

If you know you're gonna have this pattern (leading + trailing paren), just slice :

```
"(5)".slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: what the author think is best and what SO think is best may or may not be the same ;)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko maybe op couldn't thnk of another method of doing this, this might be what solves his problem without being the answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split`, use `replace`.

```
var data - "(5)".replace("(","").replace(")","");
```

Comment: 1) replace without a second argument will give undefined 2) why using replace when you just can slice? You may replace inside the string (ie `(5)5)`)

Comment: Forgot the second argument, my bad and updated. True, slice would be better for this scenario, I guess.